# How to change the label appearing in symfony 2 form templates

Tags: php, symfony

I have this in template

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

The form is appearing as

```
fos_user_registration_form_username  --input box
fos_user_registration_form_email
fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first
fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second
```

But it want to have simple labels like Username , Email etc. How to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the individual form fields instead of the form as a whole.

```
{{ form_widget(form.fos_user_registration_form_username) }}
```

In this way, you can parse a single form element. Make sure to end with

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

to output any not yet parsed fields (such as the csrf protection token).

using the above approach you can add your own labels to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

`FOSUserBundle` uses the translator system.  You need to as seen in the docs here:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/index.md

Add this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator: ~
```

To your config file (`app/config/config.yml`).

This will tell symfony to replace all the label values with the values found in the translator file (`FOSUserBundle.en.yml`).  Then the form will always print "Username" instead of "`fos_user_registration_form_username`".